# Cloning repository from BitBucket

Tags: bitbucket

I am trying to clone from bitbucket to a dev server and the project ends up in a folder. I want: httpdocs/files but I get httpdocs/ProjectName/files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `git clone origin-url .` 
(with dot)

Example:

```
hg clone https://Name@bitbucket.org/mitsuhiko/flask .
```

Comment: can you give me an example?

Comment: of course: hg clone ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/mitsuhiko/flask .